# Possible to define gradle extension properties that are not inherited by subprojects?

Tags: gradle

I want to use allprojects/afterEvaluate in a multiproject build to do something on each project based on properties that it has set.  Is there a way to set properties per project in a way that is not inherited by subprojects?

[ext.myProp](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html) works if I'm only concerned with leaf projects.  But if a parent needs to set that property too, I can't find a way to distinguish which project it was set on.  The multiproject [guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:property_and_method_inheritance) explains that properties are (begrudgingly) inherited.

This mechanism reminds me of prototypal inheritance in JavaScript.  Does gradle have a [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) equivalent?

Comment: Ok, so you need to set properties on subprojects from top level build.gradle?

Comment: I want to check at the top level whether something has been set by a specific subproject and then configure that subproject accordingly.  The problem is that the subproject might be inheriting its value from a higher level project, and I can't find a way to distinguish between "set on :parent" and "set on :parent:child".

Answer (score 0):

I dug some more and found that while there's no general way to isolate which of the [several delegated scopes](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#properties) a project property is coming from, if you're specifically looking for an `ext` property, then there is a [has](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html#org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension:has(java.lang.String)) method you can check on a specific project's ext container that does not delegate (at least not to the extent that `hasProperty` does).

So `proj.ext.has('myProp')` will be true if a value has been assigned to that project directly.

An important caveat is that properties set via `-P` or `gradle.properties` appear to be replicated into the extension containers of all projects automatically, and I don't think there's a way to distinguish that.  Extension or task properties might be easier to isolate since they're not inherited, but they're less ad hoc.